# WhatsApp - share image from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, whatsapp

is there an example to share an image with WhatsApp as its website

```
WhatsApp Messenger can handle various types of media:

    images of any type that conforms to public.image (for example, PNG and JPEG)

    images - «.wai» which is of type net.whatsapp.image
```

is this means must save the UIImage as .wai extension ? or how could be the URL scheme ?

whatsapp://image?data=UIImage&abid=

any feedback ?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20417047/whatsapp-image-sharing-ios

Answer (score -1):

hello I already had this problem before.
See if this helps you

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8nm1mkw9bpgwmni/AAB-8g2CuWTQ5jKHPj3MiUzka?dl=0

:)