# WhatsApp image sharing iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, whatsapp

I am developing an iOS application in which i have to share image on WhatsApp from my application. I found this code but it deals with only text sharing https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity

Comment: Refer to this link: http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That can be Possible using `documentationInteractionController`.
Recently I have done this using bellow code to share image From our App to whatsApp, Line, WeChat but while you click on WhatsApp icon, then you are navigation `WhatsApp` app from you app and you must return you app manually. That does not redirect again after ImageSharing.

**in .h file:-**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>
{
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentationInteractionController;
```

**in .m file**

```
- (IBAction)bocClick:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *getImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"]; //here i am fetched image path from document directory and convert it in to URL and use bellow


    NSURL *imageFileURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:getImagePath];
    NSLog(@"imag %@",imageFileURL);

    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = self;
    self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageFileURL usingDelegate:self];
    [self.documentationInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];


}

- (UIDocumentInteractionController *) setupControllerWithURL: (NSURL*) fileURL

                                               usingDelegate: (id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>) interactionDelegate {



    self.documentationInteractionController =

    [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];

    self.documentationInteractionController.delegate = interactionDelegate;



    return self.documentationInteractionController;

}
```

Comment: Where are we setting the UTI for UIDocumentInteractionController in this piece of code. Because once these 2 lines self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    self.documentationInteractionController = [self setupControllerWithURL:imageFileURL usingDelegate:self]; overwrite it

Comment: first test this code using button click even

Comment: @IronMan: `self.documentationInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";` by this you are setting UTI ! No ?

Comment: actually i use this above code in my project and i test it well and i can able to share image. this is working code i dont understand where did you stuck

Comment: Can sharing be possible through UIActivityViewController

Comment: i dont think that will be possibel wia UIactivityViewcontroller but i m not sure if some one done using this.. i done using above one :)

Comment: Does this method open WhatsApp? I mean redirect the app?

Comment: @NitinGohel I am not sure how it works. I know how works url scheme. Is this the same one. Or it is some internal feature. Will app open WhatsApp in your case?

Comment: Would you be so kind to share the UTI for WeChat and Line? thanks

Comment: if you device installed wechat and line then you can also able to share with wechat or LINE as well

Comment: It's possible to share image and text at the same time?

Comment: @Nitin Gohel in iOS 9 not working. in this code in ios 9 1)open Share Actionsheet 2) display Whatsapp icon . and than i click on this icon than display contact list for 1-2 second and than dismiss the contactView automatically. so bro. Guide me and help me